# Node js npm httpp-proxy vs http-proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, http-proxy

I want to create a proxy-server in Node.js and I'm trying to figure out what npm-package to use. I recently read some people are trying to create malware packages with similar names to frequently used npm-packages (typosquatting, [source](https://blog.liftsecurity.io/2015/01/27/a-malicious-module-on-npm/)). That made me suspicious when I saw the name 'httpp-proxy' just before installing.

Does anyone know the difference between the http-proxy and httpp-proxy packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into http-proxy and it looked like it had a big community

262,764 downloads in the last day 
1,604,883 downloads in the last week 
6,922,320 downloads in the last month

You can safely use that

Comment: Wow only 221 downloads last month for httpp-proxy. I should have thought about looking at the statistics. Feeling dumb now. Thanks for your quick response!